# Swipe page transitions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Hello i have a project in Xcode 7, i have configured swipe recognizer and now i want to do that with swipe movement change the view controller to another view controller in my storyboard i don't know what can i do. thanks for all regards

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        print("SWIPED DERECHA")
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio2", sender: nil)
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        print("SWIPED IZQUIERDA")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

Comment: now i have this with identifier in storyboard but when i swiped right enter the next view controller from left that it's correct but when i swiped left the new viewcontroller also enter from left how can i change this? thhanks  case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            print("SWIPED DERECHA")
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio2", sender: nil)                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            print("SWIPED IZQUIERDA")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio", sender: nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The easiest and most flexible way to do this is to use a `UIPageViewController` to host your pages. Each page is a child view controller hosted by the `UIPageViewController`. That's what I would recommend.

Otherwise you'll have to implement custom view controller transitions yourself. Doable, but much more complicated and a lot more difficult to figure out.

Try this link:

[How to create a page view controller in Storyboard](http://tinyurl.com/nvkhovn)

Comment: Thanks i will try to implement pageviewcontroller with pageviewcontroller i can create the design of each page in storyboard?

Comment: anybody have an example of pageviewcontroller with the diferents pages in storyboard and transitions? thanks regards

Comment: If i have a viewcontroller in my storyboard named page1viewcontroller i would use a destination segue with identifier to enter to the page2viewcontroller with effect left to right the content or right to left?

Comment: No. If you use a page view controller you wouldn't use a segue or a swipe gesture recognizer at all. The page view controller takes care of that for you. There's a sample app called "Photoscroller" that's linked from the Xcode help system that shows how to use a page view controller. It does a lot more than that, but you can ignore the details of the child view controllers that make up the pages. (They handle tiling of large images.)

Comment: thanks Duncan i will try to investigate and understand the code sorry for my english and thanks for all

Comment: Yes i want the effect of Photoscroller but i want create all the designs of the views because i want add text views, video etc it's a little bit tricky for me

Comment: So use the structure of photoscroller, but replace the child view controllers with your custom view controllers.

Comment: i will try use the pase base application in xcode or it's a bad idea?

Comment: "pase base application"? You lost me there.

Comment: page base application lool

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: in xcode there is an option to create a project that name is page-based application

Comment: I haven't used that template before. Try it and see.

Comment: Is that new with Xcode 7? I tend to ignore the different templates, use the "single view" template, and then build what I need myself, so I don't really notice new app templates.

Comment: No i think there is since xcode 5 o 6, well i haven't succeded nothing well tomorrow after the school i will try more things thanks for all Duncan